# Finding insight and apply ML process

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, seaborn, data-science

So I'm still a newbie in pandas and scikit-learn and have been given homework to finding any insight in sample data given. The only clue I've been given is that part of the insight should be related to machine learning.

After I've checked the data, it has a lot of inconsistency. It's a week shipping data that contains 2 columns, address and shipment date. I've got a problem with the address column data inconsistency, here is the example:

```
+--------------------------------+--------------+
|           to_address           | booking_date |
+--------------------------------+--------------+
| 52426 E. La Palma, Anaheim, CA | 11-12-17     |
| 52511 Blvd, Avn. Californi     | 12-12-17     |
|                                | 13-12-17     |
| 600 S.Brookhurst UTAH          | 14-12-17     |
| 190 E.Stacy Rd.,Allen,Texas    | 15-12-17     |
| 1075 W. I-20, Tex              | 15-12-17     |
+--------------------------------+--------------+
```

As you can see, the address has a lot of inconsistency in the address typing. Some address has states that are separable by commas, some don't. Some address has states in full, some missing several characters. There's also whitespaces and \n format in the address column. So far, I've been cleaning this address column by dropping whitespaces, removing \n format from the address, and creating states column by splitting the address column by comma and grab the last index (tbh, it's not working really great because of the typing inconsistency).

My question is, am I working in the right direction in cleaning the data? How to use exploratory data analysis using seaborn in this kind of data to get a possible insight? (I've tried using count plot by booking date and it shows a big gap between 12th and 15th Dec, is that insight?). Is it really applicable to the machine learning classification algorithm?

Any helpful direction would be really great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine Learnings tasks are not to provide insights. Your task is to provide insights using Machine Learning which is just a tool. ML won't tell you which algorithm to use to answer your question, you should come up with the question and then select which algorithm answers your question correctly, usually, there are several.

In your case, you have 2 columns which limits of what ML can do to help you provide insights since there are only two parameters and it's not a problem that has a clear output. Such as churn or election votes depending on various parameters.

As far as I see, these tasks does not require ML to provide insights, simple statistical models are enough.

**What might get you on the right track:**

1. When I had the most bookings?
2. Is there a correlation between the destination and date of the booking?
3. Which state orders the most?
4. Does West Coast order more than the East Coast?
5. Does countries in cold / hot climate order more?

Since you have only 2 columns you will have to create additional data for your `to_address` column. Like is it West or East coast? Is the state rich or poor? And so on, the more additional data points you create the more valuable insights you would be able to provide.

**Advanced:**

You could create an interactive plot of your destinations and color it by a count of orders per state per day. This would clearly show how your orders are being processed.

An insight is anything that answers business questions or creates new questions. So saying 'Most orders are in California' is an insight as well as ' Most orders are processed on Mondays'. Is it good insight? That is up to you and the business to decide. Having your data I do not expect to have many valuable insights because of the lack of more data.

And for future references, Machine Learning should not be applied where it does not bring any value, usually, statistics are enough.

**EDIT**

You can use:

`df['zipcode'] = df['to_address'].apply(lambda x:x.split(' ')[0])`

To create a column with zipcodes.